# DNS Configuration: server can't find ****: NXDOMAIN

Tags: linux, networking, dns, cluster, oracle-linux

*Sorry if the question title is not descriptive enough, I'm a noob @ this kind of Linux sysadmin stuff*

Hi for a college project I have to configure a Oracle RAC environment, for this task I chose this guide: https://oracledbwr.com/step-by-step-guide-to-install-oracle-19c-rac-installation-using-virtualbox/

I'm currently stuck on setting up my DNS server, this is the expected result from running `nslookup` on a configured address.

```
[root@dbwr1 ~]# nslookup dbwr-scan
Server: 192.168.24.1
Address: 192.168.24.1#53

Name: dbwr-scan.localdomain
Address: 192.168.24.43
Name: dbwr-scan.localdomain
Address: 192.168.24.42
Name: dbwr-scan.localdomain
Address: 192.168.24.41
```

This is my current output:

```
nslookup node-scan
Server:         192.168.1.1
Address:        192.168.1.1#53

** server can't find node-scan: NXDOMAIN
```

This is output after checking the `named` service's status.

```sql
systemctl status named
● named.service - Berkeley Internet Name Domain (DNS)
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/named.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2021-10-31 22:47:47 CST; 13min ago
  Process: 6930 ExecStop=/bin/sh -c /usr/sbin/rndc stop > /dev/null 2>&1 || /bin/kill -TERM $MAINPID (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 6946 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/named -u named -c ${NAMEDCONF} $OPTIONS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 6944 ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c if [ ! "$DISABLE_ZONE_CHECKING" == "yes" ]; then /usr/sbin/named-checkconf -z "$NAMEDCONF"; else echo "Checking of zone files is disabled"; fi (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 6949 (named)
    Tasks: 5
   CGroup: /system.slice/named.service
           └─6949 /usr/sbin/named -u named -c /etc/named.conf

Oct 31 22:47:47 node1.localdomain named[6949]: network unreachable resolving 'node1.localdomain/A/IN': 2001:500:9f::42#53
Oct 31 22:47:47 node1.localdomain named[6949]: network unreachable resolving 'node1.localdomain/AAAA/IN': 2001:500:9f::42#53
Oct 31 22:47:47 node1.localdomain named[6949]: network unreachable resolving './DNSKEY/IN': 2001:500:200::b#53
Oct 31 22:47:47 node1.localdomain named[6949]: network unreachable resolving './NS/IN': 2001:500:200::b#53
Oct 31 22:47:47 node1.localdomain named[6949]: network unreachable resolving 'node1.localdomain/A/IN': 2001:500:200::b#53
Oct 31 22:47:47 node1.localdomain named[6949]: network unreachable resolving 'node1.localdomain/AAAA/IN': 2001:500:200::b#53
Oct 31 22:47:47 node1.localdomain named[6949]: network unreachable resolving './DNSKEY/IN': 2001:500:a8::e#53
Oct 31 22:47:47 node1.localdomain named[6949]: managed-keys-zone: Key 20326 for zone . acceptance timer complete: key now trusted
Oct 31 22:47:47 node1.localdomain named[6949]: resolver priming query complete
Oct 31 22:49:05 node1.localdomain named[6949]: no longer listening on 192.168.24.1#53
[node1@node1 ~]$
```

This is my `named.conf` for configuring the DNS server.

```
options {
        listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1; 192.168.24.1; };
        listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; };
        directory "/var/named";
        dump-file "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
        statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
        memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
        recursing-file "/var/named/data/named.recursing";
        secroots-file "/var/named/data/named.secroots";
        allow-query { localhost; 192.168.24.0/24; };
        //empty-zones-enable no; 
        recursion yes;
        dnssec-enable yes;
        dnssec-validation yes;

        /* Path to ISC DLV key */
        bindkeys-file "/etc/named.root.key";

        managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";
 pid-file "/run/named/named.pid";
        session-keyfile "/run/named/session.key";
};

logging {
        channel default_debug {
                file "data/named.run";
                severity dynamic;
        };
};

zone "." IN {
        type hint;
        file "named.ca";
};

zone "localdomain.com" IN {
        type master;
        file "localdomain.zone";
        allow-update { none; };
};

zone "24.168.192.in-addr.arpa." IN {
        type master;
        file "24.168.192.in-addr.arpa";
        allow-update { none; };
};

include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
include "/etc/named.root.key";
```

This is the specified zone `localdomain.zone`

```
$TTL 86400
@ IN SOA node1.localdomain.com. root.localdomain.com. (
2014051001 ; serial
3600 ; refresh
1800 ; retry
604800 ; expire
86400 ; minimum
)
@ IN NS node1.localdomain.
localhost IN A 127.0.0.1
node1 IN A 192.168.24.1
node2 IN A 192.168.24.2
node1-priv IN A 192.168.10.1
node2-priv IN A 192.168.10.1
node1-vip IN A 192.168.24.31
node2-vip IN A 192.168.24.32
node-scan IN A 192.168.24.41
node-scan IN A 192.168.24.42
node-scan IN A 192.168.24.43
```

And the reverse zone:

```
$TTL 86400
@ IN SOA node1.localdomain.com. root.localdomain.com. (
2
3H
1H
1W
1H )
@ IN NS node1.localdomain.com.
@ IN PTR localdomain.com.
node1 IN A 192.168.24.1
node-scan IN A 192.168.24.41
node-scan IN A 192.168.24.42
node-scan IN A 192.168.24.43
1 IN PTR node1.localdomain.com.
41 IN PTR node-scan.localdomain.
42 IN PTR node-scan.localdomain.
43 IN PTR node-scan.localdomain.
```